# How to unbind link to object TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got an menu item (array):

```
this.menu = [new Menu('default_name', 'menu_1', null, 'Main', false)];
```

There is another array `let roles = [1, 2, 3];` that I iterate in loop:

```
let names = [];

for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
   if(roles[i] == 1) {
       let name = this.menu[i].name = "Article1";

   } else if (roles[i] == 2) {
      let name = this.menu[i].name = "Article2";
   }

   else if (roles[i] == 3) {
      let name = this.menu[i].name = "Article3";
   }

    names.push(name);
}
```

When I assign a new value to`this.menu.name` for each iteration it rewrites previous object: `this.menu.name`.

How to fix it?

I tried to reassign `this.menu[i]` inside loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
    let a = this.menu[i];
}
```

But it does not work, I still change main object (array).

Comment: Do you want a `Menu` to have multiple names?

Comment: And why do you want to assign a name to an array?

Comment: Yes, I have array of menu items and I want to use this array for each iteration.

Comment: I want to assign new name menu item for each of roles in loop. So, I understand issue, I use one array and try to change first attribute in object inside array. It always rewrites previous value.

Comment: I dont need to change in menu array, but I want to get this value and assign to another variable for further using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of menus. There's a menu in it. This gives

```
[
  0: {/* data */} // menu
]
```

Then, in your loop, you decide to fix a key of that array. That gives

```
[
  0: {/* data */}, // menu
  name: 'Article[1|2|3]'
]
```

As you can see, you never touch the menu. This might be your issue.

Now I did not understand your question, but with what you're doing, I'm sure this will help you understand.

Comment: Okay I will try to explane a bit more